# Trimming inputs in laravel controllers

Tags: php, laravel

My application is running into an error due to strings being stored in my database which have got double spaces in the middle and are not being trimmed properly.

In my controllers I use laravel's validator, which I believed used the trimStrings middleware to deal with trimming inputs however my code is still storing strings with double spaces in my database.

Here is my code for my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $room = Room::find($request->roomid);

    $data = $this->validate($request, [
        'name' =>'required|string',
        'volume' => 'required',
        'newrefurb'=> 'required'
    ]);

    $updateroom = $room->updateRoom($data);
}
```

Here is my code for my model:

```
public function updateRoom($data)
{
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->volume = $data['volume'];
    $this->newrefurb = $data['newrefurb'];

    $this->save();

    return $this->id;
}
```

Here the name field was the problem containing double white space in the middle of the string.

What is the correct way to handle strings with double spacing?

Answer (score 0):

The `TrimStrings` middleware trims the spaces from the beginning or the end of the string, not in the middle. Here is a helper that you can create and use it to trim extra spaces from anywhere in the string:

```
function trimExtraSpaces($text)
{
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
}
```

-- EDIT

As in the comments below was suggested, in order to store it without the extra space, you can make a mutator of the column, so in your Model, put this:

```
public function setNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['name'] = trimExtraSpaces($value);
}
```

Comment: You could add this as a SET Mutator for attributes you specifically require.

Comment: @gingaWRATH The problem I am having is that when using {{ room->name }} in my blade files this appears to remove the double white spacing, so when the value is used in my eloquent query it doesn't match what is stored in the database

Comment: Yes @StevenBendell that's what GingaWRATH suggested, so take a look at my edit now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @nakov's answer this is because the `TrimStrings` just uses php's [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function which will just strip whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

If you would like the `TrimStrings` middleware to replace all double spaces with a single space as well then you could add the following method to the `TrimStrings` middleware:

```
/**
 * Transform the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function transform($key, $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $this->except, true) || !is_string($value)) {
        return $value;
    }

    return  trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $value));
}
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that when using {{ room->name }} in my blade files this appears to remove the double white spacing, so when the value is used in my eloquent query it doesn't match what is stored in the database